# Deleting objects when exiting a program

Tags: c++, qt

I have a simple client-server qt program. At the end of program I want client to send some settings to the server so that him would save them.

```
void Client::closeEvent(QCloseEvent* event)
{
finishSession();
event->accept();
}


void Client::finishSession()
{
QByteArray* array = new QByteArray;
QDataStream in(array, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_9);

in << quint16(6) << m_name << quint16(vecContacts.size());
for (int i=0; i<vecContacts.size(); i++)
{
    in << vecContacts[i]->checkName();
}
for (int i=0; i<vecContacts.size(); i++)
{
    in << vecContacts[i]->getText();
}
pClientSocket->write(*array);
}
```

But when I put data into a stream server do not react on that anyhow though everything worked fine during the program.
I think that happens because object of the Server class was destroyed when I closed Client widget (server object is hiden all time ). But I am neither sure nor know how to solve this problem. My function Main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication app(argc, argv);

Server* m_pServer = new Server;
cout << "Server port is " << m_pServer->getServerPort() << endl;


Client* p1Client = new Client (m_pServer->getServerPort() );
p1Client->show();
m_pServer->show();


return app.exec();
}
```

Am I right about deleting server object ? If so how to solve that ?

Found out that if I shows my server object in main function everything works fine

Part of server's code which concerns to that problem:

```
void Server::slotReadyRead()
{
cout << "server slotReadyRead" << endl;
QTcpSocket* senSocket = (QTcpSocket*)sender();
QDataStream out(senSocket);
quint16 var = 0;
out >> var;
switch (var)
{
case 5:
    cout << "MESSAGE RECEIVED" << endl;
    getMessage(senSocket);
    break;
case 1:
    logName(senSocket );
    break;
case 2:
    logPass(senSocket);
    break;
case 3:
    newAccount(senSocket);
    break;
case 4:
    newContact(senSocket);
    break;
case 6:
    saveAccountSettings(senSocket);
    break;
case 7:
    openAccountSettings(senSocket);
    break;
}
}

void Server::saveAccountSettings(QTcpSocket* sender)
{
cout << "Server saving setting" << endl;
QDataStream out(sender);
QString acName;
QString contacts("");
QString add;
// read account name
out >> acName;
quint16 num;
//read number of contacts
out >> num;
// read first contact name
out >> add;
contacts = add;
QStringList list;
for (int i = 1; i < num; i++)
{
    out >> add;
    list.append(add);
    contacts += ("+" + add);
}
QSettings settings("Chat", "Server");
settings.setValue("/settings/" + acName + "/contacts", contacts);

for (int i=0; i<num; i++)
{
    add = list[i];
    out >> contacts;
    settings.setValue("/settings/" +acName + "/" + add, contacts);
}
cout << "Server saved settings" << endl;

}
```

Comment: Did you right Server yourself? Is it a QObject? Does is have an associated QObject parent? Is it necessary to instantiate server using new?

Comment: @WernerErasmus I wrote by myself. It has QWidget as a parent

Comment: Post the code, or some link to the code

Comment: dose your application only has one event loop at Client widget, by closing that your server will close because this object dose not have any eventloop running

Comment: **Why are allocating your `Client` and `Server` objects dynamically?** just allocate them on the stack, and the compiler will handle their life time for you, effectively destroying them and all their children `QObject`s once your main function returns.

Comment: @saeed any ideas how to solve it ? except show() method ?

Comment: @VityaMiroshnychenko you can move Server to a separate thread and start it, I suggest you change whole design , is that a test or practice only project

Comment: @saeed thank you. Yes, it is just a practice but what is wrong with my design ?

Comment: Is your server object also a widget?

Comment: @VityaMiroshnychenko please check these examples [fortuneclient](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-fortuneclient-example.html) and [threadedfortuneserver](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-threadedfortuneserver-example.html)